nextjs: Letting the user to pick few Web Components from an external library and use them to create a Static page (???)
I'm new to Next.js, and I'm trying to implement a feature that seems simple, but I'm a bit stuck. Here's the flow I want to achieve:

The user can view a list of Web Components (retrieved from an external repo). Those components are built using any stack the user chooses. The users can add, remove, and update them at any time.
The user selects a few Web Components from the list.
The user clicks a button, and the app generates a static page with those Web Components (and relative configuration). The goals is to serve that page (that the facto becomes a SPA) by a CDN.

I'm unsure how to implement the step 3 in Next.js. (Is it even possible to generate static pages dynamically like this with Next.js?)
Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated!
Note: the Web Components are not part of the code at all.... they are dynamically fetch from a DB (or a repo). I imagine to have a list of zip file and each zip file have all the files of the web component
Many thanks!
I've tried to create a basic hello world component and import it in next js. I get erros. I've found few links that seems directing in the correct direction (see https://dev.to/swyx/how-to-use-web-components-with-next-js-and-typescript-4gg1) but not getting there...
